# Diferença entre <!DOCTYPE html> e <html>

Tags: html, html5

Eu sempre utilizei ambos em um código HTML, mas não sei a real diferença entre eles. Alguém poderia me explicar a diferença entre  e ?

Comment: @Maniero, as questões passadas por você apenas falam da funcionalidade do <!DOCTYPE html> ou como escrevê-lo corretamente. No entanto, isso eu já sei. O que eu gostaria de saber é a diferença entre essa declaração e a tag <html>.

Answer (score 1):

O `<html>` em si é uma tag para iniciar o arquivo, basicamente.
Apesar da sintaxe parecida, o Doctype não é uma tag do HTML. O Doctype HTML é uma declaração para informar ao navegador qual é a versão do HTML utilizada no arquivo. Essa declaração vem antes das tags HTML, portanto, geralmente é apresentada na primeira linha de um código. É recomendado que sempre usemos o Doctype para o browser detectar a versão do HTML.

Answer (score 1):

**Diferenças gerais entre HTML5 e HTML4**

1. Sintaxe simplificada e clara

A sintaxe no HTML5 é extremamente clara e simples em comparação ao HTML4. Um exemplo disso é o elemento DOCTYPE. No HTML4, a declaração DOCTYPE era muito confusa e demorada e usada para referenciar uma fonte externa. No entanto, no elemento HTML5 DOCTYPE foi feito extremamente simples. Por exemplo, um mero <! DOCTYPE html> é suficiente para especificar o tipo de documento.

2. Elementos multimídia

O HTML5 contém suporte embutido para arquivos multimídia integrados na página da web por meio de tags de vídeo e áudio. Anteriormente, no HTML4, o conteúdo multimídia era integrado às páginas da Web por meio de plugins de terceiros, como Silverlight e flash.

3. Acessando a localização geográfica do usuário

Anteriormente no HTML4, era uma tarefa extremamente complicada obter as localizações geográficas dos visitantes que visitavam o site. Foi até difícil quando o site foi acessado através de dispositivos móveis. Por outro lado, no HTML5 é extremamente fácil obter a localização do usuário. O JS GeoLocation do HTML5 pode ser aproveitado para identificar a localização do usuário que acessa o site.

4. Armazenamento do lado do cliente

No HTML4, para armazenar dados importantes no lado do cliente, foi usado o cache do navegador. No entanto, esse cache é limitado e não suporta o mecanismo de armazenamento relacional. No HTML5, esse problema foi solucionado por meio de banco de dados Web SQL e cache de aplicativos que podem ser acessados ​​pela interface JavaScript do HTML5.

5. Comunicação do servidor cliente

No HTML4, a comunicação entre o cliente e o servidor foi feita por meio de streaming e sondagens longas, pois não há soquetes da Web disponíveis no HTML4. Pelo contrário, o HTML5 contém soquetes da web que permitem a comunicação full duplex entre clientes e servidores.

6. Mecanismo de encadeamento JavaScript

No HTML4, o JavaScript e a interface do navegador com a qual o usuário interage são executados no mesmo encadeamento que afeta o desempenho. O HTML5 contém a API JS Worker Web, que permite que a interface JavaScript e Browser seja executada em threads separados.

7. Compatibilidade do Navegador

Como mencionado anteriormente, o HTML4 é um padrão estabelecido para o desenvolvimento de aplicativos de navegador e está em uso há mais de 10 anos. Por esse motivo, o HTML4 é compatível com quase todos os navegadores da web.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Diferenças de tags em HTML4 e HTML5**

Várias tags no HTML4 foram removidas do HTML5 ou sua funcionalidade foi modificada. A seguir, estão algumas das tags removidas do HTML5 ou com funcionalidades diferentes no HTML5 em comparação ao HTML4.

1. removido `<Object>` Adicionado no HTML5

O HTML4 continha uma tag `<applet>` usada para exibir os applets em um navegador da web. No entanto, no HTML5, essa tag do applet foi removida. Para exibir itens do tipo applet, uma nova tag `<object>` foi introduzida no HTML5.

2. `<Acronym>` removido `<Abbr>` Adicionado no HTML5

O HTML4 continha uma tag `<acronym>` usada para exibir abreviações em um navegador da web. No entanto, no HTML5, essa tag foi removida. Uma nova tag `<abbr>` foi introduzida no HTML5.

3. Diferença no uso da tag `<hr>`

A tag `<hr>` foi usada para desenhar uma linha no HTML4 e em todas as versões anteriores do HTML; no entanto, no HTML5, a funcionalidade dessa tag foi alterada e usada para definir uma quebra temática na página da web.

4. Diferença no uso da tag `<a>`

No HTML4 e nas versões anteriores, a tag `<a>` foi usada como âncora e também para se referir a um link. No HTML5, a tag `<a>` é usada apenas como um hiperlink. Mas se a tag href for removida da tag `<a>`, a tag `<a>` poderá ser usada como um espaço reservado para outros hiperlinks.

5. Atributo de esquema removido da tag `<meta>` no HTML5

A tag  é definida na seção de cabeçalho do documento HTML e contém informações sobre os dados. Nas versões anteriores do HTML, incluindo o HTML4, essa tag costumava conter um atributo chamado esquema que definia o esquema do documento. No entanto, no HTML5, essa tag foi removida.

**Mudanças nos atributos**

A seguir, estão alguns dos atributos que foram modificados no HTML5.

Nas versões HTML4 e HTML anterior, o atributo script era usado na tag link para se referir a JavaScript ou outros scripts semelhantes. No HTML5, não é necessário usar esse atributo de script.

No HTML5, a tag `<table>` pode ter apenas um atributo Border e o valor desse atributo pode ser apenas zero ou um. Anteriormente, a tag  tinha muitos atributos.

Nas versões anteriores do HTML, a tag  não tinha o atributo charset que define a codificação de caracteres padrão para a página da web. Este atributo foi adicionado em HTML5.

[**saber mais ....**](https://www.w3c.br/pub/Cursos/CursoHTML5/html5-web.pdf)

[**HTML5test**](https://html5test.com/index.html)